# Is 'that' missing from this phrase

Tags: word-usage

'It's me has to clean up the mess,always me.'

This is from an everday speech from the book A Daughter's Duty' by Maggie Hope.
Is this phrase missing 'that'? Shouldn't it be 'It's me that has to clean up the mess,always me.'.

How is this sentence grammatically correct? Can you tell me where the subject verb and object are?

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes, it should - but this is colloquial speech, which isn't always grammatical.

Comment: It's colloquial and could be AmE or BrE, fyi.

Comment: It's not standard English.  It's an example of colloquial speech (or dialect) from the North East of England. The author is from County Durham, although I haven't read the book, I suspect it's set somewhere around there.

Comment: It's grammatical in its dialect. It wouldn't be in Standard English.

Comment: It is not only BrE. It is AmE also. Gees.

Comment: Standard: It's me **who**, not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase "It's me has to clean up the mess, always me." is grammatically correct, but it could be seen as informal or conversational in tone. Omitting the conjunction "that" is common in informal speech and writing.

However, including the conjunction "that" in the sentence would make it sound more formal and would make it clear that "me" is the subject of the sentence: "It's me that has to clean up the mess, always me."

Comment: How is it grammatically correct? Can you explain please?